# What is the maximum width we can set in Outerbounds for Chrome app?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os

I have a chrome box which can support two monitors. Can I have single chrome app with dimensions 3840x1080 (width =3840, height =1080) for outerbound dimensions. 
 
 I tried this but it does not work, is there any possible way to do this? 
 
Single chrome app to stretch on two monitors immediately after I open the chrome app

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {  
  chrome.app.window.create('index.html', {  
    'outerBounds':   
 { 'width': 3840,  
      'height': 1080 }  
  });  
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to require a minimum height or width for your window, you can use `minHeight` or `minWidth` in your [bounds specification](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#type-BoundsSpecification).

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(
  function() {
    chrome.app.window.create('index.html', { 
        outerBounds: { 
            width: 3840,
            height: 1080,
            minWidth: 3840,
            minHeight: 1080
         } 
    }); 
  });
```

Comment: Thanks Sarah. that worked. I have another question, I connected two monitors to the chromebook and I am trying to extend a window but only half of it is seen on one of the screen. Do you know any settings to see the window on both screens

Comment: @Amanda Hi Amanda! It's hard to figure that out from a comment. It would be great if you could post that as a new question with the code that you've tried and any other details that would help, or search SO first to see if anyone has already answered that. Thanks!